# How to add more selections or less selections by keys

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using `Mac, SublimeText2`

When I used the mouse to click `got_value`, the words equal to `got_value` will be highlighted,

Then I press `cmd+D` , only the first 2 `got_value` were selected,

How could I make more `got_value`s to be selected ? (by keyboard but not mouse click)

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to select more instances.

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to unselect the last instance.

Or, to highlight them all

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>